# Position a footer div outside of the container

Tags: html, css, footer, html5boilerplate

How can I get my footer to sit on the bottom of the page outside of the container?  The template is based on the boilerplate.

What CSS do I need to use to make it sit at the bottom?

**HTML:**

```
</div><!-- end of container -->

    <div clear="clear"></div>
            <div id="footer" class="w960">
        <div id="footerHolder">
            <div class="foot left"></div>

            <!--
            <div class="foot right">
                FOLLOW US:
                <div id="social">
                    <a href=""><div id="fb" class="socialIcon"></div></a>
                    <a href=""><div id="tw" class="socialIcon"></div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{width:960px;margin:0px auto 40px auto;}
#footer{width:100%;clear:both; height:66px;background:#2d2d2f;}
#footerHolder{width:960px;margin:auto;}
```

Comment: By moving the markup as needed? You're question doesn't seem specific enough I think.

Comment: @MicahHenning The markup is in the question above I just cannot get the CSS right for it to sit at the bottom.

Comment: Which element do you want to sit at the bottom? And do you want that element fixed to the page or to the window?

Comment: @MicahHenning I want the footer to sit at the bottom of the page currently its like http://cl.ly/image/0H45063X1y26 that and I want it fixed to the page I think

Comment: I don't know what your footer is... I see a bunch of semantically-devoid elements... What's the ID of the one you want positioned at the bottom of the page? And do you want it to remain at the bottom of the page or the bottom of the window? The picture you sent doesn't really seem to help me.

Comment: @MicahHenning The main footer div is #footer the holder is holding the text within it.  I want it to remain under the content div at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Instead of all this hand waving, why not make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Asad I just have but it loads how it should I will try again

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for exactly but shouldn't your #footerHolder contain the #footer?
Also, div clear="clear"
is not required since you are specifying the clear:both property in #footer.
This should rest nicely at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I am trying to get the footer at the bottom of the page instead of half way up the content.  I changed them around and no it is correct